# Eigenvalue problem: show that it only has negative eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the eigenvalue problem

$$u''-\frac{3}{4x^2}u=\lambda u, \ \ \ u(1)=0,\ u(2)=0$$

I want to show that this eigenvalue problem only has negative eigenvalues. I multiplied the equation by $u$:
$$(u')'u-\frac{3}{4x^2}u^2=\lambda u^2$$

Integrating the LHS (by parts):

$\int_1^2(u')'u-\frac{3}{4x^2}u^2dx=[u'u]_1^2-\int_1^2(u')^2dx-\frac{3}{4}\int_1^2\frac{u^2}{x^2}dx$

Now, $u(1)=u(2)=0$, so the first term equals $0$, and $-\int_1^2(u')^2dx \leq 0$ and also $\frac{3}{4}\int_1^2\frac{u^2}{x^2}dx \leq 0$ because the integrands are $\ge 0$ (because of the $(.)^2$) and we integrate from $1$ to $2$.

So, the LHS is $\leq 0$.

And the RHS: $\lambda\int_1^2u^2dx \geq 0$

Therefore $\lambda \leq 0$.

Is that correct so far?

How, do I show that $\lambda \neq 0$? I thought about solving the initial value problem
$$u''-\frac{3}{4x^2}u=0, \ \ \ u(1)=0,\ u(2)=0$$

The solution of the IVP is $u=0$ if I didnt make any mistakes. Is that any 'contradiction' which means that $\lambda$ can't be equal to $0$?

Comment: You are on the right track.

Comment: @JackyChong I found that $u=0$ is not allowed as a eigenfunction. Is that everything?

Comment: what else do you want to prove?

Comment: Nothing, just wanted to know if the reasoning for $\lambda \leq 0$ is correct